# Heroku Eclipse Plugin Install Error

Tags: heroku, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install the `Eclipse plugin` for `Heroku (Eclipse EE Juno SR1)`, but I'm running into the following errors:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ning.async-http-client,1.6.5.20120903-0645
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.2.0.20120903-0645
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.2.0.20120903-0645
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.2.0.20120903-0645
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.2.0.20120903-1050
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jboss.netty,3.2.5.Final-20120903-0645
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.slf4j.api,1.6.4.v20120130-2120
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://eclipse-plugin.herokuapp.com/install

Comment: what version of eclipse did you use? "eclipse-plugin.herokuapp.com/install" this link must be https.so Did you follow ssh key generation steps? can you tell me which link did you follow?

Comment: @Luke [Please follow this Link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse) Lets know if you face any issues

Comment: That's the link I followed.  I'll try again.

Comment: I'm getting the same error after retrying again.  I have ssh keys already, so I didn't need additional keys.

Comment: I think I know what the issue is.  I installed EGit before installing the Heroku plugin, which I think affected the Heroku install.  It is now resolved.  Thanks!